# Wordpress site displays inline css code

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a site http://kaniamea.com/turtle/ and if you see the source code you will see the following. This is inline code and it comes with the Theme. Is there a way to organize this code in a separate stylesheet in the child folder?
Also is there a way to limit the head tags. It seems there are many redundant tags there.
Thanks a lot!

```
<style type="text/css"> .ssba {




                                    }
                                    .ssba img       
                                    {   
                                        width: 40px !important;
                                        padding: 6px;
                                        border:  0;
                                        box-shadow: none !important;
                                        display: inline !important;
                                        vertical-align: middle;
                                    }
                                    .ssba, .ssba a      
                                    {
                                        text-decoration:none;
                                        background: none;
                                        font-family: Indie Flower;
                                        font-size:  20px;


                                    }</style><style type="text/css"> #header, #main, #topbar-inner { max-width: 1250px; } #container.one-column { } #container.two-columns-right #secondary { width:250px; float:right; } #container.two-columns-right #content { width:910px; float:left; } /*fallback*/ #container.two-columns-right #content { width:calc(100% - 280px); float:left; } #container.two-columns-left #primary { width:250px; float:left; } #container.two-columns-left #content { width:910px; float:right; } /*fallback*/ #container.two-columns-left #content { width:-moz-calc(100% - 280px); float:right; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 280px); width:calc(100% - 280px); } #container.three-columns-right .sidey { width:125px; float:left; } #container.three-columns-right #primary { margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px; } #container.three-columns-right #content { width:880px; float:left; } /*fallback*/ #container.three-columns-right #content { width:-moz-calc(100% - 310px); float:left; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 310px); width:calc(100% - 310px);} #container.three-columns-left .sidey { width:125px; float:left; } #container.three-columns-left #secondary {margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px; } #container.three-columns-left #content { width:880px; float:right;} /*fallback*/ #container.three-columns-left #content { width:-moz-calc(100% - 310px); float:right; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 310px); width:calc(100% - 310px); } #container.three-columns-sided .sidey { width:125px; float:left; } #container.three-columns-sided #secondary { float:right; } #container.three-columns-sided #content { width:880px; float:right; /*fallback*/ width:-moz-calc(100% - 310px); float:right; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 310px); float:right; width:calc(100% - 310px); float:right; margin: 0 155px 0 -1190px; } body { font-family: Ubuntu; } #content h1.entry-title a, #content h2.entry-title a, #content h1.entry-title , #content h2.entry-title { font-family: Yanone Kaffeesatz Regular; } .widget-title, .widget-title a { line-height: normal; font-family: Open Sans Light; } .entry-content h1, .entry-content h2, .entry-content h3, .entry-content h4, .entry-content h5, .entry-content h6, #comments #reply-title, .nivo-caption h2, #front-text1 h1, #front-text2 h1, .column-header-image { font-family: Open Sans Light; } #site-title span a { font-family: Yanone Kaffeesatz Regular; } #access ul li a, #access ul li a span { font-family: Droid Sans; } body { color: #444444; background-color: #FCFFC6 } a { color: #1693A5; } a:hover,.entry-meta span a:hover, .comments-link a:hover { color: #D6341D; } #header { background-color: ; } #site-title span a { color:#1693A5; } #site-description { color:#999999; } .socials a { background-color: #1693A5; } .socials-hover { background-color: #D6341D; } /* Main menu top level */ #access a, #nav-toggle span { color: #333333; } #access, #nav-toggle {background-color: #f0f37a; } #access > .menu > ul > li > a > span { border-color: #d2d55c; -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #ffff92; -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #ffff92; box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #ffff92; } #access a:hover {background-color: #fdff87; } #access ul li.current_page_item > a, #access ul li.current-menu-item > a, #access ul li.current_page_ancestor > a, #access ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a { background-color: #fdff87; } /* Main menu Submenus */ #access > .menu > ul > li > ul:before {border-bottom-color:#2D2D2D;} #access ul ul ul:before { border-right-color:#2D2D2D;} #access ul ul li { background-color:#2D2D2D; border-top-color:#3b3b3b; border-bottom-color:#222222} #access ul ul li a{color:#BBBBBB} #access ul ul li a:hover{background:#3b3b3b} #access ul ul li.current_page_item > a, #access ul ul li.current-menu-item > a, #access ul ul li.current_page_ancestor > a, #access ul ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a { background-color:#3b3b3b; } #topbar { background-color: #000000;border-bottom-color:#282828; box-shadow:3px 0 3px #000000; } .topmenu ul li a { color: #CCCCCC; } .topmenu ul li a:hover { color: #EEEEEE; border-bottom-color: #1693A5; } #main { background-color: #FFFFFF; } #author-info, #entry-author-info, .page-title { border-color: #1693A5; background: #F7F7F7; } #entry-author-info #author-avatar, #author-info #author-avatar { border-color: #EEEEEE; } .sidey .widget-container { color: #333333; background-color: ; } .sidey .widget-title { color: #666666; background-color: #F7F7F7;border-color:#cfcfcf;} .sidey .widget-container a {color:;} .sidey .widget-container a:hover {color:;} .entry-content h1, .entry-content h2, .entry-content h3, .entry-content h4, .entry-content h5, .entry-content h6 { color: #444444; } .sticky .entry-header {border-color:#1693A5 } .entry-title, .entry-title a { color: #444444; } .entry-title a:hover { color: #000000; } #content h3.entry-format { color: #333333; background-color: #f0f37a; } #footer { color: #AAAAAA; background-color: ; } #footer2 { color: #AAAAAA; background-color: #F7F7F7; } #footer a { color: ; } #footer a:hover { color: ; } #footer2 a, .footermenu ul li:after { color: ; } #footer2 a:hover { color: ; } #footer .widget-container { color: #333333; background-color: ; } #footer .widget-title { color: #666666; background-color: #F7F7F7;border-color:#cfcfcf } a.continue-reading-link, #cryout_ajax_more_trigger { color:#333333 !important; background:#f0f37a; border-bottom-color:#1693A5; } a.continue-reading-link:after { background-color:#D6341D; } a.continue-reading-link i.icon-right-dir {color:#1693A5} a.continue-reading-link:hover i.icon-right-dir {color:#D6341D} .page-link a, .page-link > span > em {border-color:#CCCCCC} .columnmore a {background:#D6341D;color:#F7F7F7} .columnmore a:hover {background:#1693A5;} .file, .button, #respond .form-submit input#submit, input[type=submit], input[type=reset] { background-color: #FFFFFF; border-color: #CCCCCC; box-shadow: 0 -10px 10px 0 #F7F7F7 inset; } .file:hover, .button:hover, #respond .form-submit input#submit:hover { background-color: #F7F7F7; } .entry-content tr th, .entry-content thead th { color: #444444; } .entry-content fieldset, #content tr td,#content tr th, #content thead th { border-color: #CCCCCC; } #content tr.even td { background-color: #F7F7F7 !important; } hr { background-color: #CCCCCC; } input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], input[type="file"], textarea, select, input[type="color"],input[type="date"],input[type="datetime"],input[type="datetime-local"],input[type="month"],input[type="number"],input[type="range"], input[type="search"],input[type="tel"],input[type="time"],input[type="url"],input[type="week"] { background-color: #F7F7F7; border-color: #CCCCCC #EEEEEE #EEEEEE #CCCCCC; color: #444444; } input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] { color: #444444; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-color: #CCCCCC; box-shadow: 0 -10px 10px 0 #F7F7F7 inset; } input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="password"]:hover, input[type="email"]:hover, textarea:hover, input[type="color"]:hover, input[type="date"]:hover, input[type="datetime"]:hover, input[type="datetime-local"]:hover, input[type="month"]:hover, input[type="number"]:hover, input[type="range"]:hover, input[type="search"]:hover, input[type="tel"]:hover, input[type="time"]:hover, input[type="url"]:hover, input[type="week"]:hover { background-color: rgba(247,247,247,0.4); } .entry-content code { border-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-color:#1693A5;} .entry-content pre { border-color: #CCCCCC; background-color:#F7F7F7;} .entry-content blockquote { border-color: #EEEEEE; } abbr, acronym { border-color: #444444; } .comment-meta a { color: #444444; } #respond .form-allowed-tags { color: #999999; } .reply a{ background-color: #F7F7F7; border-color: #EEEEEE; } .reply a:hover { background-color: #f0f37a;color: #1693A5; } .entry-meta .icon-metas:before {color:#CCCCCC;} .entry-meta span a, .comments-link a {color:#666666;} .entry-meta span a:hover, .comments-link a:hover {color:;} .nav-next a:hover {} .nav-previous a:hover { } .pagination { border-color:#ededed;} .pagination span, .pagination a { background:#F7F7F7; border-left-color:#dddddd; border-right-color:#ffffff; } .pagination a:hover { background: #ffffff; } #searchform input[type="text"] {color:#999999;} .caption-accented .wp-caption { background-color:rgba(22,147,165,0.8); color:#FFFFFF} .tempera-image-one .entry-content img[class*='align'],.tempera-image-one .entry-summary img[class*='align'], .tempera-image-two .entry-content img[class*='align'],.tempera-image-two .entry-summary img[class*='align'] { border-color:#1693A5;} #content p, #content ul, #content ol, #content, #frontpage blockquote { text-align:Default ; } #content p, #content ul, #content ol, .sidey, .sidey a, table, table td { font-size:15px; word-spacing:Default; letter-spacing:Default; } #content p, #content ul, #content ol, .sidey, .sidey a { line-height:1.7em; } #content h1.entry-title, #content h2.entry-title { font-size:34px ;} .widget-title, .widget-title a { font-size:18px ;} #content .entry-content h1 { font-size: 38px;} #content .entry-content h2 { font-size: 34px;} #content .entry-content h3 { font-size: 29px;} #content .entry-content h4 { font-size: 24px;} #content .entry-content h5 { font-size: 19px;} #content .entry-content h6 { font-size: 14px;} #site-title span a { font-size:38px ;} #access ul li a { font-size:14px ;} #access ul ul ul a {font-size:12px;} .nocomments, .nocomments2 {display:none;} #header-container > div { margin:40px 0 0 0px;} #content p, #content ul, #content ol, #content dd, #content pre, #content hr { margin-bottom: 1.0em; } #nav-toggle { text-align: left; } #toTop {background:#FFFFFF;margin-left:1400px;} #toTop:hover .icon-back2top:before {color:#D6341D;} #main {margin-top:20px; } #forbottom {margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px;} #header-widget-area { width: 33%; } #branding { height:120px; } </style>
```

Comment: Is this all just static CSS that is being output in the head or is it dynamically generated from theme options? If it's just static all you need to do is move it to a CSS file and enqueue it.

Comment: It is dynamic generated from a file called custom-styles.php.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

Answer (score 3):

### The Problem

The reason that CSS is being output in the head instead of loaded from a file is because the theme has style options that need to be generated dynamically. The easiest (and laziest) way to do this is to just generate the CSS and dump it into the head. Here is a stripped down example of what is happening:

```
add_action('wp_head' function() {
    echo '<style>.some-selector { color:' . $user_selected_color ' . ; }</style>';
});
```

This is bad because this CSS cannot be cached by the browser; it will be included in the response to every single request.

### The Solution

An alternative approach would be to write the dynamically generated CSS to a file every time the options are saved. This isn't quite as easy as the current approach, but it is still not difficult.

```
add_action('theme_name_options_saved', function() {
    //determine the path to the css file
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $css_path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/theme-name/dynamic.css';

    ob_start();

    /**
     * Call whatever function or include whatever file that 
     * outputs your dynamic CSS here.
     */

    //write the css to the file
    $css = ob_get_clean();
    file_put_contents($css_path, $css);

    //update the version number
    update_option('theme_name_css_version', time());
});

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    //determine the url of the css file
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $css_path = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/theme-name/dynamic.css';

    //enqueue the css file
    wp_enqueue_style('theme_name_dynamic_css', $css_path, array(), get_option('theme_name_css_version'));
});
```

### The Catch

`theme_name_options_saved` is not a built in action. You're going to have to dig through the theme's code, figure out when the options are saved and call that action yourself.

```
do_action('theme_name_options_saved');
```

That shouldn't be too difficult, but it may take some searching.

You're also going to have to figure out how the theme is computing its dynamic CSS and incorporate it into the action hook. You mentioned it was in a file called `custom-styles.php` so it may be a simple as including that file.

---

Not too hard right? Kind of begs the question, *"Why don't theme developers do it this way to begin with?"* Some of the most popular *paid* themes just dump all of their dynamic CSS into the head.

Comment: Thank you for this! Yes, it does sound complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Just to chime in with the plugin that creates the internal CSS: it's the [Simple Share Buttons Adder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/) plugin.